# Drupal module for insert csv file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, drupal, drupal-7

I try to run this code, but when i press import i don't get error message. When i go into mysql database, every row is blank, and i have about 3500 rows.. Can someone tell me what to do..? Here is a code:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Implements hook_permission()
 */
function module_name_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer uploader' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer Uploader'),
      'description' => t('Allow the following roles to upload csv files to the server.'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function module_name_menu() {
  $items['file-uploader'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upload a File',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'description' => 'Import a csv',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('module_name_import_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer uploader'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Builds a form that will allow users to upload csv files
 * 
 * @see
 *   hook_menu()
 */
function module_name_import_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form['notes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<div class="import-notes">A few notes when uploading. <ul><li>Make sure the file is in a .csv format.</li><li>Columns should be in *this* order</li><li>Be sure to click the "Upload" button when you select a csv.</li></ul></div>',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://tmp/',
  );
  $form['import'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Import'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('The uploaded csv will be imported and temporarily saved.'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://tmp/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'),
    ),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array (
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Import'),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Submit handler for module_name_import_form()
 */
function module_name_import_form_submit($form, $form_state) {


  $file = $_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'];

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ",")) !==false)
    {

      $firstname = $fileop[0];
      $lastname = $fileop[1];
      $email= $fileop[2];



       db_query("INSERT INTO csvupload (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email') ");


  }

  fclose($handle);
}
```

And there is simple csv file:

```
asd,asd,@yahoo
asd,asd,@gmail
asd,asd,@hotmail
asd,asd,@gmail
```

Comment: Is there an error, if so please update your question with it.

Comment: No, there is no error, just keep proceeded to max time (300s) and then when you go to database you can see about 3000 rows, and there is nothing to show..(I hope you understand my problem) thanks in advance :) @miltonb

Comment: Try putting a try..catch block around the db_query or even better yet use drupals watchdog to output the SQL values. BTW your SQL statement is not secure, use parameterized queries as shown here : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `$_FILES ['file']['tmp_name']` get you the uploaded file? Updated the code with correct way of working with managed files.

```
/**
 * Submit handler for def_import_form()
 */

function def_import_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $temp = file_load($form_state['values']['import']);
  $file = file_create_url($temp->uri);

  $handle = fopen($file, "r");

  while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ",")) !==false)
  {
    $firstname = $fileop[0];
    $lastname = $fileop[1];
    $email= $fileop[2];

    /** add values to db **/
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
```